# How to validate Observable Collection with INotifyDataErrorInfo interface

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, mvvm, inotifydataerrorinfo

I'm developing `WPF` application with `MVVM` pattern and using `Prism` Framework.

I have a basic data class as follow.

```
public class ProductDecorator : DecoratorBase<Product>
{
    private string _ProductShortName;
    private Boolean _IsSelected = false;

    // I have omitted some code for clarity here.

    [Required]
    public int ProductID
    {
        get { return BusinessEntity.ProductID; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(() => BusinessEntity.ProductID == value,
                            () => BusinessEntity.ProductID = value);
        }
    }

    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return _IsSelected; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _IsSelected, value);
        }
    }
 }
```

I create the observable collection of the above data class in the ViewModel.

```
public class SaleInvoiceViewModel {

    private ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> _productDecorators;
    public ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> ProductDecorators
    {
        get { return _productDecorators; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _productDecorators, value); }
    }
}
```

And I bounded this observable collection to the listbox in the View.

```
<telerik:RadListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ProductDecorators}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,10,5,5" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <CheckBox Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductShortName}" FontSize="14" />
         </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
  </telerik:RadListBox.ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>
```

From the above context, I want to validate "the user must select at least one item in the list box". In other words, `IsSelected` property must be **true** in one of the `ProductUmDecorator` class from the **observable collection** `ProductUmDecorators`.

Currently I use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` Interface and `Data Annotations` for validation rule. I've lost that **how should I implement my problem to achieve this validation**?

Comment: I'd have gone with a SelectedProductUmDecorator party, and mark that as invalid if empty.  You must have some other way of indicating a selected element in the collection [edit: duh, yeah], so maybe try marking ProductUmDecorators as invalid if none are selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow related with this topic but no solid answer. So I decided to post my solution as the answer to this problem.
The context of the problem is to check "**the user must select one item in the listbox which is bound with observable collection**".

First step, the item (entity) in the `ObservableCollection` need `IsSelected` property.

```
public class ProductDecorator : DecoratorBase<Product>
{
     private string _ProductShortName;
     private Boolean _IsSelected = false;

     // I have omitted some code for clarity here.

     public Boolean IsSelected
     {
         get { return _IsSelected; }
         set
         {
             SetProperty(ref _IsSelected, value);
         }
     }
}
```

Second step, each item in the `ObservableCollection` must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then you can access the `PropertyChanged` eventhandler.

Third step, you need to attach the following method to `CollectionChanged` event handler of `ObservableCollection`.

```
public class SaleInvoiceViewModel {

     private ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> _productDecorators;
     public ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> ProductDecorators
     {
          get { return _productDecorators; }
          set { SetProperty(ref _productDecorators, value); }
     }

     public SaleInvoiceViewModel() {
           _productDecorators= new ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator>();
           _productDecorators.CollectionChanged += ContentCollectionChanged;
     }

     public void ContentCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
     {
          if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
          {
              foreach(ProductDecorator item in e.OldItems)
              {
                   //Removed items
                   item.PropertyChanged -= EntityPropertyChanged;
              }
          }
         else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
         {
              foreach(ProductDecorator item in e.NewItems)
              {
                  //Added items
                  item.PropertyChanged += EntityPropertyChanged;
              }     
         }       
    }
}
```

Look carefully `EntityPropertyChanged` method in the above code. This method will trigger whenever any properties changed in any items in the `ObservableCollection`. Then, you can simply call `Validate` method in the `EntityPropertyChanged` method.

```
private void EntityPropertyChanged( object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e )
{
      if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
            this.Product.ValidateProperty("ProductUmDecorators");
}
```

If the changed property is `IsSelected`, the `ValidatedProperty` method will be run.
I will omit the detail implementation of `ValidateProperty` method. This method will try to validate the property with `DataAnnotations` and trigger the ErrorChanged event when there is any errors. You can learn detail [here](http://blog.pluralsight.com/async-validation-wpf-prism).

Finally, you need to implement custom `DataAnnotation` `ValidationAttribute` in your Entity/ViewModel/Decorator class where your `ObservableCollection` property existed as the following code.

```
public class SaleInvoiceViewModel {

     private ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> _productDecorators;
     [AtLeastChooseOneItem(ErrorMessage = "Choose at least one item in the following list.")]
     public ObservableCollection<ProductDecorator> ProductDecorators
     {
         get { return _productDecorators; }
         set { SetProperty(ref _productDecorators, value); }
     }
}

public class AtLeastChooseOneItem : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid( object value, ValidationContext validationContext )
    {
        ProductDecorator tmpEntity = (ProductDecorator) validationContext.ObjectInstance;
        var tmpCollection = (ObservableCollection<ProductUmDecorator>) value;

        if ( tmpCollection.Count == 0 )
            return ValidationResult.Success;

        foreach ( var item in tmpCollection )
        {
            if ( item.IsSelected == true )
                return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult( ErrorMessage );
    }
}
```

That is a little complex solution but that is the most solid solution I find out so far.